# Why do I still get nulls?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the earliest reading for that day and it should not be null.

```
update #tmpLargestAccounts set EarliestMeterReading=
SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(MeterReading, 0)
FROM MeterReading
WHERE ISNUMERIC(MeterReading) = 1
    AND  isnull(MeterReading,'~') <> '~'
    AND DateRead = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - CONVERT(int, @DaysBack), 101)
    AND Miu = #tmpLargestAccounts.Miu
ORDER BY ReadDate ASC
```

It should give some other reading which is not `null`. That can be reading one minute later but not `null`. But I still get quite a lot of nulls.

Comment: My guess, is that this is part of a larger query, and that you are only showing us a small part of an `OUTER APPLY`. While the small section that you have shown should not return any nulls, it doesn't mean that if you reference this column in the outer query it will not be null. If this only part of a larger query, can you post the full query?

Comment: Also, IsNumeric is really a pretty horrible function. It can and will return false positives. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/why-doesn%e2%80%99t-isnumeric-work-correctly-sql-spackle

Comment: @GarethD It is not a part of an inner query this code updates a column in the temp table. I noticed that for that date there is just no data for some people but still is not null should do it's job and not show it. Is it still possible to get nulls if actually null is returned despite using is not null condition.

Comment: @wizwind If it is part of query that updates the temp table, then it sounds exactly like it is part of a larger query. What you have posted does not compile, you have a column reference `#tmpLargestAccounts.Miu` but no reference to the table `#tmpLargestAccounts`. Can you post the actual query that you are running?

Comment: @GarethD This query updates a column in the temp table and this column has a lot of nulls.

Comment: @wizwind If a particular meter was not read on the day in question, what should go in the column `EarliestMeterReading` if it should not be `NULL`?

Comment: @GarethD meters take reading in every 15minutes so a value which is null at a particular time must not be taken in the results, rather the reading 15min sooner/later can be taken. In this case I need earliest reading that is why I have sorted and taken top 1 to include in the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code should work, why aren't you using `IS NOT NULL`?

```
MeterReading IS NOT NULL
```

I could imagine that the query is failing.  If `MeterReading` is a number, then yo should be getting a type conversion error.

Comment: If MeterReading were a numeric datatype, then there would be no reason to use the IsNumeric function. So obviously that column is string. And - guessing - there are certain "flag" values present which is why your suggestion won't work. There is a need to filter both rows with a null value and rows with a value of '~'.

Comment: @SMor . . . Are we reading the same question?  I see no hint about a special value, just "I want the earliest reading for that day and it should not be null."

Comment: @GordonLinoff I used 'MeterReading is not null' too.

Comment: @smor can you explain what do you mean by hint about a special value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT TOP 1 MeterReading
FROM MeterReading
WHERE MeterReading IS NOT NULL
    AND DateRead = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - CONVERT(int, @DaysBack), 101)
    AND Miu = #tmpLargestAccounts.Miu
ORDER BY ReadDate ASC
```